# Running SOLR on a desktop application without servlet contains like tomcat,Jetty

Tags: solr

I was wondering if anyone has run Apache SOLR without running it on an application server ? I'm writing a JavaFX application for Mac and Windows and it requires a search functionality like faceting, synonyms etc. I just want to know if it's possible to index, search, delete and update documents into SOLR directly like a plain Java Application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in addition to @Persimmonium gave, another way of using Solr is EmbeddedSolr.

```
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer
```

Please know that "The simplest, safest, way to use Solr is via Solr's standard HTTP interfaces. Embedding Solr is less flexible, harder to support, not as well tested, and should be reserved for special circumstances." http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr

Having said that , I had seen implementations of Solr with EmbeddedSolr based on usecases where applicable as justified.

Answer (score 0):

Solr requires a servlet container right now, no way around it, but you could either:

1. run jetty/tomcat in embedded mode, it is quite easy to do so in newer versions. This way you just have one jvm running.
2. use Lucene instead of Solr, Lucene now has a faceting module, you can use a SynonymFilter etc. Maybe you have to write a bit more of code.

Comment: I just didn't want my application to be a memory hog. So I will have 2 JVM instances running, one for Jetty/SOLR and one for JavaFX. Is there a way I can use one JVM instance for both SOLR & JavaFX ? I don't think that's possible but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: yes there is, as I said in option 1, you can embed jetty https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: I don't get it. JavaFX is a client application which will run through the main method .. I know I can deploy SOLR in embedded Jetty which will make me run two JVM's one for JavaFX (Client) and SOLR/Jetty(Server). How is it possible to run both client and server applications in one JVM instance ?

Comment: using jetty (or any other container for that matter, the ones that are able to) means that you run it from your main(), not in a separate jvm. Check the doc on how to embed it, there are code samples

Comment: You [can run Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer) without a servlet container.  We have been doing this for testing our custom fields - it spins up a Solr instance in the same JVM with no embedded servlet container and tears it down once the test has run.

Comment: @Prunge: so, have you tried deleting jetty jars from your Solr installation when running with EmbeddedSolrServer ??

Comment: @Persimmonium we use Maven for dependency management, and it does not pull in any Jetty JARs.  It pulls in servlet-api-2.4.jar but that is only an API JAR and not a full-blown servlet container.

Comment: good to know, I was assuming jetty was started under the covers